# Why C++11 and PHP closures require declaring the closed-over variables?

Tags: php, c++, closures, c++11

Function literals in both C++ and PHP require programmer to specify which variables they are using from the current lexical context. What's the reason behind this requirement?

I guess it's not meant for the compiler/interpreter, because one can statically infer this information from function literal's body. Is it only for drawing the reader's attention?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For C++11 at least, `[=] () {...}` will automatically pull in all and only those local variables which the function body uses. (Or, equally, `[&]...`)

You can specify individual variables to be captured by reference or by value if you have any specific needs beyond this catch-all.

In PHP, variables are created when their name is first used, so I expect the declaration is to make sure no new variables mask the old ones. A bit like the `global` keyword.

Comment: OK, in case of PHP it (almost) makes sense.

Comment: It's all about control with C++. I love how it lets you control your closures.

Comment: @bstamour -- indeed, and the ability to explicitly specify which variables are captured could be useful for guarding against _inadvertently_ captured variables (say, with a long expression that's copy-pasted from somewhere else), which is of course particularly important when capturing is done by reference...

Answer (score 0):

well can't say for php nor that i got your question 100% - but...in c++ variable total partakes in the lambda function closure. the major premise of this is that it can change its value, being a reference.

Comment: The [Postmodernism Generator](http://www.elsewhere.org/pomo/) appears to have a SO account.